# Run plugin's shell in cakephp 2.0

Tags: shell, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0

I have created a new CakePHP 2.0 app and want to run a plugin's shell.

```
<?php
// app\Plugin\Tmaker\Vendors\Shells\TmakerShell.php
class TmakerShell extends Shell {  
}
```

However, I can't see it when running `Console/cake` from the command-line.

Please advise my what I have missed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [latest documentation](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/blob/master/en/console-and-shells.rst), the path for shells has changed to `app/Console/Command/`.

Move your shell to the following location: `app/Plugin/Tmaker/Console/Command/TmakerShell.php` (not sure if plugin directory names are camel-cased in CakePHP 2.0, but it seems to work either way.)

```
<?php
class TmakerShell extends Shell {
    public function main() {
        $this->out('It works!');
    }
}
```

As CakePHP 2.0 requires you to load plugins manually, you also need to update `app/Config/bootstrap.php` by adding `CakePlugin::loadAll();` or `CakePlugin::load('Tmaker');` to the last line.

You should then be able to access your shell from the command-line. It looks like this in Windows:

```
C:\xampplite\htdocs\cake2\app>..\lib\Cake\Console\cake Tmaker.tmaker

Welcome to CakePHP v2.0.0-beta Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: C:\xampplite\htdocs\cake2\app\
---------------------------------------------------------------
It works!
```

Comment: How can i use Same plugin model in TmakerShell. For example i have model name as abc.php in app/Plugin/Tmaker/Model folder now i want to use this model in TmakerShell. How this can be done ?

Comment: @PardeepSingh you might need to use plugin syntax: `public $uses = array('Tmaker.Abc');` – http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-plugin-syntax

Comment: That is what am doing but getting Error: Plugin Tmaker could not be found.
But when i run cake with -app /path/app then command is not getting executed . No output from cake if i use -app option.