# How do i install the cakephp forum plugin by Miles J?

Tags: cakephp

Am pretty sure this is a cake 1.3 question - the plugin is not compatible with 2.0

I am trying to install the Miles J plugin for cakephp for forums, which can be found here:
http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/forum

I am struggling with his tutorial though. Sigh.

SO, here is what i have done -

1. downloaded his plugin
2. moved his plugin into my /app/plugins/forum folder (so contents are Config, Console...View, webroot, readme.md -- eg /app/plugins/forum/Config)
3. downloaded the cakedc utils plugin
4. moved this to the /app/plugins/utils folder (so its contents read Controller, Lib, locale...license.txt, readme.md -- eg /app/plugins/utils/Controller)
5. done steps "2" and "3" from that page i have linked to above - where "2" starts with: "The forum plugin was designed to interact with an external users..." and "3" with: "Admin routing must be enabled in app/config/core.php."
6. And now it gets confusing. He writes about some sort of install program... weren't the last two steps install steps? Are they separate? I don't know! Anyway, I go to run the "cake" command he has, and I get an error ~ "cake not found"
7. Navigate to: /cake_install/cake/console (where "cake_install" is the base path for my cake folder, of course)
8. Run the cake command... but this time I am totally unsure what the "/path/to/app" Miles writes about means. Is it the path to the plugin (which would make sense to me) or to the cake_install folder (i mean, I am *in* it already, seems a bit redundso).
9. try both of them - each time i get an "Error: Class InstallShell could not be loaded." error, which isn't very useful.

Any ideas on what I should do next? I don't mind doing a manual install, but am i on the right track? Where steps "2" and "3" meant to be run? Is there something simpler to do to get this thing working?

If you don't know, could someone recommend a simple forum plugin/tool/thing i can buy that i can use instead? I am not particularly tied to this forum plugin right now...

cheers!

BONUS QUESTION:
at the end of step "3" Miles helpfully suggests:
"It is also a good idea to create a "forum" folder within your app/tmp folder, and chmod it to 777. "

All well and good, but do i *just* need to make a forum folder, or do i need to, say, tell cakephp to use it? Why is it a good idea to make a forum folder? Should i? What happens if i don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you seem to mix up cake 1.3 and 2.0. please read the documentation and tutorials. the correct path for plugins like this one in 2.0 is /APP/Plugin/PluginName/... (also note the casing which is very important).

as you already pointed out, the forum plugin is a "plugin". therefore it needs a surrounding app (application) for it to work. if you name it "site", your forum would be in `/site/Plugin/Forum/`

then you should navigate to this `/site` folder with your shell and there execute the `cake` commands. Also make sure you loaded the Plugin via CakePlugin::loadAll() in your bootstrap.
then it will find the Plugin shells.

The 2.0 doc can be found here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/

Comment: I am mixing 1.3 and 2.0? I did not know that! I am using 1.3 - the plugin only works only 1.3 ... so i am only using 1.3

Comment: aha - that is an important information you should have pointed out in your question (always mention your cake version). in this case why are your folders uppercase? It should be `controller` and `config` (as opposed to Controller and Config) then. PS: the 3.0 version of the Forum Plugin is compatible with cake2 by the way!

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that! Ok, so all the folders are lower case then (am using 2.3 of the plugin). Also, i am assuming the bootstrap thing is a cake 2 issue? Finally, why do i go to /site/plugin/forum (excuse the caps, on ipad) in the shell, but out the code in /site/app/plugin/forum?

Comment: /APPNAME/plugins/forum in 1.3 (note the plural `plugins`) :) and yes, bootstrap plugin loading is 2.0 only.

Comment: Ah, ok, let. Me give this a whirl when i get home. Also, any ideas about the tem folder this "Miles" guy suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another thread that might help you run shell commands.
[Run plugin's shell in cakephp 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979442/run-plugins-shell-in-cakephp-2-0)

The command you will run will look something like this
C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app> ..\lib\Cake\Console\cake Forum.install