# Forum Plugin for Cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, forum

I need the forum plugin for `cakephp 1.3`. I couldn't find this old version. Does anyone know where can I find it and how can I install it? I could just find the new version of cupcake from [here](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/forum).

Comment: Take a look at this question, it may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003642/how-do-i-install-the-cakephp-forum-plugin-by-miles-j

Answer (score 0):

The `2.x` branch of the Forum plugin still supports CakePHP 1.3, as can be read in the [Readme](https://github.com/milesj/Forum/blob/2.x/readme.md) of that branch.

Just clone the repository and then checkout the 2.x branch:

> cd app/plugins/
>   git clone https://github.com/milesj/Forum.git
>   git checkout 2.x

Then you should be ready to integrate it into your app.

Answer (score 0):

Forum v2.0
A fully robust and powerful [CakePHP](https://www.sagipl.com/cakephp-development/) forum plugin.

**Requirements**

CakePHP 1.3.x (Tested with 1.3.9)
PHP 5.2.x, 5.3.x
Utils Plugin - https://github.com/CakeDC/utils